# Scaling PDF content and page dimensions from command line

Tags: command-line, pdf

I have a set of images stored as separate PDF files.  One image per file.  Each image takes up one PDF page.

I need to re-scale all of these images, preferably at the command line, so that the image content and the page dimensions of the PDFs are both scaled relative to their original sizes/dimensions.  For example: scale all the images by 50% should shrink the size of the image and the dimensions of the page.

Already tried:

- pdfpages + latex: will re-scale the image but dimensions of the pages stay the same.
- pdfjam: same problem; can re-scale but page dimensions want to be letterpaper or a4.
- convert (imagemagick): converts to raster, which I don't want.
- ghostscript: seems to scale based on absolute new page size, and I need relative page size.

I know one of these must work.  I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.  I'm on Mac but a Linux solution would work just as well.

Answer (score 27):

`pdfjam` works for this.

```
pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --paper a5paper in.pdf
```

Comment: Yes, and you can also just add `--landscape` to do exactly that.

Comment: I wanted to really just scale both dimensions by some factor. In order to keep the initial image ratio you need to specify the explicit target size, e.g. `--papersize '{16in,10in}'` for some 16:10 ratio. Otherwise you might end up with unexpected whitespace around the image. You could extract the initial size as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39538/384195).

Comment: Note that while this is potentially useful for many use cases, this example usage _does *not*_ answer the question as-asked (and indeed, is listed as a non-workable solution).  That said, it seems like pdfjam can (now?) _mostly_ do this, as it does have a `--scale` option.  That said, that option _does not_ auto-scale the page size, too, as was requested in the original question.  So, very useful for many, no doubt, but not strictly a valid answer to this question as asked... though could perhaps be adapted to be one??

Comment: For US "letter" paper sizes (8.5 x 11 inches), use: `pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --paper letter in.pdf`

Comment: @lindes can you detail why `pdfjam` does not answer the question? OP complains that "can re-scale but page dimensions want to be letterpaper or a4", but he seems to ignore the fact you can use custom page size with `--papersize` option, as @bixel pointed out

Comment: @robertspierre Sorry, I don't really remember.  It's possible that it couldn't at the time, and enhancements have made it now work?  Not sure... I haven't been using it since.  That said, it's in the original question, and this answer doesn't explain why (taking you at your word that) `pdfjam` actually can work, so... maybe edit the answer, or suggest an edit?

Answer (score 26):

I think I found one: http://community.coherentpdf.com/

`cpdf -scale-page "0.5 0.5" in.pdf -o out.pdf`

Comment: Yes thanks. I use `cpdf -scale-to-fit "210mm 210mm" in.pdf -o out.pdf` and it works great

Comment: could not find `cpdf` in ubuntu repos but for me `pdfjam` as per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185224/188451) answer did the trick.

Comment: I used `pdfposter`  as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697091/divide-a-a3-document-in-two-a4-documents/697094#697094).

Comment: Thanks, this is a magical tool!

Comment: Where did you find documentation on this? I can't find this answer by searching for scaling pdf on linux command line.

Comment: @young_souvlaki, there's an [online user manual](https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf) with detailed examples

Comment: As far as I can see, `cpdf` doesn't scale the images, only the page settings of the PDF.

Comment: `cpdf` for some reason broke the layout

Comment: Notice that, as far as I understand, `cpdf` is not free software

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you want:

https://github.com/tavinus/pdfScale

NB: As at 2021-07-14, there is no way to specify an arithmetic scale factor, but as pdfScale *does* accept custom page sizes, the following posix shell script overcomes that limitation:

```
#!/bin/sh
inFile=yourFilenameHere.pdf
scalePercent=50
# NB: 50% linear scaling takes A4 to A6
# For 50% area scaling (A4 to A5), use scalePercent=70
oldSize=$(pdfinfo $inFile | grep '^Page size')
oldWidth=$(echo "$oldSize" | awk '{print $3}')
oldHeight=$(echo "$oldSize" | awk '{print $5}')
newWidth=$(($oldWidth * scalePercent / 100))
newHeight=$(($oldHeight * scalePercent / 100))
pdfScale.sh -r "custom pts $newWidth $newHeight" $inFile
# default output filename is yourFilenameHere.CUSTOM.pdf
```

There's a page at https://ma.juii.net/blog/scale-page-content-of-pdf-files which explains the history behind the project - interesting stuff! HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem finding a tool that can do something like that; I want to change page size of and rotate a PDF document, but without scaling contents. And I just realized  [`pdfedit`](http://pdfedit.cz/en/user_doc.html) (which is a GUI tool, however), can do it:

- After the document is opened, go to Page/"Edit page metrics", and then edit the x,y positions of left upper/right lower corners, and then Change.
- After that, can go to Page/"Rotate page 90 Degrees"

Note that:

- if you do the rotation first, and the page size change second, things may go wrong!
- Once you save these changes, they may be saved as a "revision" seen by `pdfedit`

  - To "flatten" the revisions, use Tools/Flatten - procedure may be a bit unintuitive though, for details see [pdfedit.user / pdfedit-support - How to save changes in a "non-incremental update" way? - Gmane](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.pdfedit.user/897)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I tried [`pdfScale.sh`](https://github.com/tavinus/pdfScale) and [`cpdf`](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries), and `cpdf` works for me.
`cpdf` will stretch the cover and content to fill the entire page without extra white space left.

Here is the command, you need to calculate the scale ratio  when use `cpdf` with the option `-scale-page`

```bash
cpdf -scale-page "x_ratio_not_size y_ratio_not_size" input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

I use a fish function `cpdfscale` which depends on `pdfinfo` and `cpdf` to convert pdf files for my apple devices.

Here is the `cpdfscale.fish` source code:

```shell
function cpdfscale
  # Get pdf file origin size
  set -l dim_x (pdfinfo $argv[3] | grep -a "Page size" | cut -d\: -f2 | cut -dx -f1 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//')
  set -l dim_y (pdfinfo $argv[3] | grep -a "Page size" | cut -d\: -f2 | cut -dx -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//')
  echo Origin Page Size\t :\t $dim_x x $dim_y pts
  echo Scaled Page Size\t :\t $argv[1] x $argv[2] pts

  # Calc scale ratio
  set -l sx (math $argv[1] / $dim_x)
  set -l sy (math $argv[2] / $dim_y)
  echo Scaled Page Ratio\t :\t $sx x $sy

  # Set output file and convert
  if test (count $argv) -gt 3
    echo Scaled Output File\t :\t $argv[4]
    cpdf -scale-page "$sx $sy" $argv[3] -o $argv[4] &> /dev/null
  else
    set -l outfile (echo $argv[1]x$argv[2] - (basename $argv[3] .pdf).pdf)
    echo Scaled Output File\t :\t $outfile
    cpdf -scale-page "$sx $sy" $argv[3] -o $outfile &> /dev/null
  end
  echo "Scale finished"
end
```

Usage:

`cpdfscale x_size_in_pts y_size_in_pts input.pdf [output.pdf]`.

if the output file is not specified, a new file name with origin name
and new file page dimensions `${x_size_in_pts}x${y_size_in_pts} - ${origin_name}.pdf`
will be used.

The following command convert any pdf file for my iPad Air4 which has a screen with size 1640 x 2360 pts.

```bash
cpdfscale 1640 2360 origin.pdf scaled.pdf
```

The core command to get my work done is:

```
cpdf -scale-page "3.253968 4.173453" origin.pdf -o scaled.pdf
```

Here is the output:

```
>=>  cpdfscale 1640 2360 origin.pdf
Origin Page Size     :   504  x 565.479 pts
Scaled Page Size     :   1640 x 2360 pts
Scaled Page Ratio    :   3.253968 x 4.173453
Scaled Output File   :   1640x2360 - origin.pdf
Scale finished

>=>  cpdfscale 1640 2360 origin.pdf scaled.pdf
Origin Page Size     :   504  x 565.479 pts
Scaled Page Size     :   1640 x 2360 pts
Scaled Page Ratio    :   3.253968 x 4.173453
Scaled Output File   :   scaled.pdf
Scale finished
```

Answer (score -1):

What I wanted was to fit multiple pages into one page with vertical merge. The following helped:

```bash
# The following with merge every 3 pages into one (Every 3 pages are merged,  one below the other)
# You can also use --frame option for debugging. It will add each page on a frame.
pdfjam --nup 1x3 --outfile out.pdf in.pdf
```

Input:

```
p1
---
p2
---
p3
---
p4
---
p5
```

Output:

```
    p1
    p2
    p3
    ---
    p4
    p5
```

Refs:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565094
- https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I've seen so far in the [`cpdf`](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries), you can use `-scale-page` to stretch both the page size and the page contents

```sh
specified_size=(200 300) # 200 pt x 300 pt

read -a input_size <<< "$(pdfinfo input.pdf | grep 'Page size:')" # get the input size

x_ratio=$(echo "scale=4; ${specified_size[0]} / ${input_size[2]}" | bc)
y_ratio=$(echo "scale=4; ${specified_size[1]} / ${input_size[4]}" | bc)

cpdf -scale-page "$x_ratio $y_ratio" input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok.