# scale pdf to exact size

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf

I need a program for Linux which can scale pdf files to a specified size, stretching them if needed. I would prefer a command line program, but something with a gui is ok too.

I found a lot of programs to scale the pdf, but they all scale proportionally, and then just add a white border. But I need something which will stretch the pdf file, so it has the exact needed size without white border.

I know stretching may make the pdf look odd, but I have some pdf files which just need to be a 1.5 mm higher, so it is less then 1% I need to stretch them, so I still think it will look ok.

Comment: By scaling, do you mean the page size? For example A4 to A3?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, it's the page size i need to scale. But that also require scaling the content, so the page is still full, even if that require stretching the content

Comment: @MTilsted Have you tried [`cpdf -scale-page "0.5 0.5" in.pdf -o out.pdf`](https://superuser.com/questions/676013/scaling-pdf-content-and-page-dimensions-from-command-line) as listed in that post as an example command to see if it scales the content you need? http://community.coherentpdf.com/

Comment: Using a PDF reader and a PDF printer, start the reader on the file, issue Print, choose the PDF printer and set custom scaling to more than 100%. My viewer is [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/).

Comment: @MTilsted And if none of that works, here's a post that talks about a potential solution using ImageMagick with `-density`, `-resize` and perhaps `-scale` switches... https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25044. Hopefully it is as easy as HarryMC suggests and that will work for you though nice and easy.

Comment: Would you please upload a sample of the PDF files? Different files would be applicable to different ways. (Text or image, has margin or not...)

Comment: @Skyler that would not really help. The graphics files are created by different persons using different software, so there are no system in things such as margins, colors and so on -(

Comment: Would it help if converting the PDF files into PNG files, scaling the PNG files and then converting them back to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

My method requires a PDF viewer and a PDF printer to be installed.
The viewer that I'm using is [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/),
available for Windows, Linux and Mac.

In Foxit Reader, I can open a PDF file and print it to the PDF printer.
This viewer has in its Print dialog the option to print using a scale.
I can set the "Custom scale" to an integer percent number, and it will scale
all elements by that percentage.

Using this viewer, you may stretch the elements by one percent, but cannot
specify anything less. This may be enough in your case, or be too much,
since you say that you need to stretch by the precise amount of "1.5 mm higher".

---

For a method that is more precise than the above, one method I can imagine
is exporting all pages as images, scaling up and cropping the images,
then packing them up again in a PDF.

You will lose here the ability to select partial text, because everything
will be images.

Comment: But I need to make the image 1.5 mm higher, without increasing the width. So it need to stretch all the content so it get's slightly higher. And the print option can't do that.

Comment: That's too precise for any utility that I know. The only method I can imagine is exporting all pages as images, scaling up the images, then packing them up again in a PDF. You will lose here the ability to select partial text, because everything will be images.

Answer (score 0):

An image in a PDF is fairly often at different X and Y PLACEMENT ratios even when the stated resolution is squares, thus if you can use a text editor via commands (such as SED) and  a decompressed image paged PDF say using  QPDF (free for commercial users whereas cpdf is free for private users). Then you could edit the placements.
Take this small example of scan 3 pixel by 3 pixels

```
%PDF-1.7
%ÂµÂ¶
1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 72 72]/Rotate 0/Resources<</XObject<</Img0 5 0 R>>>>/Contents 4 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>> endobj
4 0 obj <</Length 30>>
stream
q
72 0 0 72 0 0 cm
/Img0 Do
Q

endstream
endobj

5 0 obj <</Length 27/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 3/Height 3/BitsPerComponent 8/SMask null/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB>>
stream
ÿ   ÿ   ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ    ÿÿÿ€€€
endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000111 00000 n 
0000000235 00000 n 
0000000314 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 6/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
485
%%EOF
```

[image]  SAY desired is 99 units high [image]

Then we simply edit the second 72 to 99 at both the page height and the image size.

`3 0 obj <</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 72` **99**`]/Rotate 0/Resources<</XObject<</Img0 5 0 R>>>>/Contents 4 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>> endobj`

4 0 obj <</Length 30>>
stream
`q`
`72 0 0` **99** `0 0 cm`
`/Img0 Do`

NOTE this is specific to one image per page as if there were dozens of objects per page then thats dozens need adjustments and usually more complex.

NOTHING has changed extract the image it will still be 3 square pixels squared. @ 1/72 dpi It will NOT come out stretched that is just an illusion for the MEDIA printing. This is how scanners may say 199 dpi horizontal and 201 vertical when in reality the import is 200 square.

Answer (score -1):

This [info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371214) is from our friends from [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). As advised on that answer,

> You can use pdfjam with the --papersize argument to set the output paper size. You may also need to use --scale and --offset if you want to do more than resize the page and its contents together.
>
> ```
> pdfjam --papersize="$(LC_ALL=C pdfinfo model.pdf | awk '/^Page size:/ {printf "{%fbp,%fbp}", $3, $5}')" file.pdf new_file.pdf
> ```

You can also find other methods using ghostscript from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446552/resizing-a-pdf-using-ghostscript) from StackOverflow.

Comment: That don't work, because pdfjam adds white border around the content, instead of stretching it. Imagine I start with a pdf which is 2x2 cm, and I want to end up with something which is 4x8 cm, without any white borders. Then a square in the original pdf, would be a rectangle in the destination pdf.

Comment: What about ghostscript?

Comment: Have you tried --scale?

Comment: @alamar your question is addressed to me or MTilsted?

Comment: @MTilsted - the answer mentions `--scale` but it wasn't considered

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried opening the pdf through a tool like Photoshop or sketch and then stretching it there?

You can then re-save it with it.

Done it plenty of time and you can get pixel-level precision.